# Angular jsFiddle example doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I can't understand why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zishe/8HxjM/60/) doesn't work. The error is

```
Error: Argument 'TodoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

I guess the issue is simple, but I can't solve it. In general, I want to change the text periodically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get your fiddle working I changed the following:

1. Changed **onLoad** to **no wrap (body)**
2. Changed the framework to **AngularJS 1.0.1**

Here is a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spu5y/2/) based on your original fiddle note the following changes based around bypassing jQuery for DOM/model updates:

1. Angular's built in [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) service is used instead of `setInterval` and `clearInterval` since modifying the model outside of AngularJS shouldn't be done if easily avoided. If you want to do so be sure and look at [$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply).
2. Whenever you update the model in JavaScript any bound UI elements will automatically be updated.

Comment: Changing onLoad to nowrap in jsFiddle also helped me thanks! WHHYY is this necessary?

Comment: For more details see [this post](http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/)